# Kubernetes Ingress not Cleaning path

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I have this ingress in my server.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mycompany-production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "30"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - ra2.mycompany.com.br
      secretName: ra-production-us2-certmanager-certificate
  rules:
    - host: ra2.mycompany.com.br
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: mycompany-production-deployment-nodeport
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /conteudo/
            backend:
              serviceName: seo-production-deployment-nodeport
              servicePort: 80
```

Actually, I expect that when I call ra2.mycompany.com.br/conteudo/health, for exemple, it touch the **seo-production-deployment-nodeport/health**, but it is going to **seo-production-deployment-nodeport/conteudo/health** receiving an 404 answer.

Looking in my ingress it does not seems to have an error. I just do not know why it's not "cleaning" the path as expected. The requests in normal **/** path is happening as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
      - path: /conteudo/
        backend:
          serviceName: seo-production-deployment-nodeport
          servicePort: 80
```

You're hitting `ra2.mycompany.com.br/conteudo/health` so of course it goes to this backend, as defined in the ingress rules.

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`  just means that `/` in your url is forwarded to `/` in the backend matching the path set in rules, **not** matching the rule serving `/`

To make it easy to understand: when you run a webserver which only serves everything under a **base path** let's say `/mysite` but you do not want the people using your ingress to see /mysite/ you set your `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /mysite` and if they hit `<domain>/foo` it actually goes to your backend `/mysite/foo`

Comment: Yes, it's going to expected backend, but I was expecting it to remove the "/conteudo" in the call and call the backend directly in the /health, in the example case.

Comment: no, you understood the rewrite target annotation the opposite way of what it's designed for. It removes what you set on the annotation, even though the backend serves under a base url. Each of your backends might serve under / and you allow to use one or the other via the ingress paths you set. Urls starting with /conteudo will ALWAYS hit the second rule but your current rewrite target does nothing as / means redirect / to / on the backend, not / on the ingress.

Comment: Yes, I tried some variations in the rewrite path, including /conteudo and just removing the line. And it always send to my backend with the complete path (the /conteudo in the path too).

Can you please give an example of what you are trying to explain? Sorry, I'm kind of new in this kubernetes stuffs.

Comment: IF the /health is to be served by mycompany-production-deployment-nodeport then you need to hit ra2.mycompany.com.br/health

Comment: Yes. It’s correct. But I have two healths. One in the root and one in the Seo. Anyway, I’m using health just as an example, because it should be correct for any path after /content. I think I couldn’t make me clear :(